# Creating one layout for different screens in android

Tags: android-layout

I have created a layout that has xml files, these xml files are joined by "include" to make one  layout in hdpi.I have texts in these files. I have given size for the text in dp. However, when i run the app in smartphone with mdpi screens, my layout heigh can not fit the screens. My layout's not resizing. Please help me with this question

Comment: Are you using `dp` measurements for margins?

Comment: You probably need to specify the margins in `dimens` then depending on the screen size.